# After Submit button is hit hide form and have 'thank you' box appear

Tags: css, forms, input, replace, submit

After the user fills out this from and clicks the submit button located at the bottom, I would like the form to disappear and have a 'thank you' box appear in it's place.  If anyone knows how to complete this please let me know!

[image: Thank you text box]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvffpjxb/6/)

```
<form class="container" action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
              <label>First Name
                <input id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>Last Name
                <input id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>Email
                <span class="error">Please enter a valid email address</span>
                <input id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>Phone
                <span class="error">Please enter a valid phone number</span>              
                <input id="phone" maxlength="80" name="phone" size="20"    type="tel" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>City
                <input id="city" name="city" maxlength="40" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>State/Province
                <input id="state" maxlength="20" name="state" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label id="co">Company
                <input id="company" name="company" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>Comments
                <textarea id="comments" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" onkeyup="test()"></textarea>
                <input id="sub" type="submit" disabled="disabled" />
              </label>

                <div>                
                    <select  hidden="true" id="00N6A000008yXMN" name="00N6A000008yXMN" title="Product Interest">
                    <option value="">--None--</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="Visiant">Visiant</option>
                    <option  value="Tessellate">Tessellate</option>
                </select><br>

                <select  hidden="true" id="lead_source" name="lead_source">
                    <option value="">--None--</option>
                    <option value="Internal">Internal</option>
                <option value="Trade Show">Trade Show</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="Website">Website</option>
                <option value="Direct Marketing">Direct Marketing</option>
                <option value="Social Media">Social Media</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select><br>
                </div>
            </form>

body {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f78e2a;
  text-align: center;
} 
form {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f78e2a;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Lato;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-title {
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Lato";
  letter-spacing: 70px;
}

input[type="tel"] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f9a558;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f9a558;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}


input[type="text"]:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="text"]:visited {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="tel"]:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="tel"]:visited {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f9a558;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

textarea:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#co {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

label:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

select,
label {
  height: 50px;
  width: 48%;
  margin: 2% 1%;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Lato";
}

#sub {
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #B9B9B9;
  color: #959595;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-left: 1%;
  display: block;
}

button:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #f78e2a;
}

@media (max-width: 426px) {
  label {
    width: 98%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 426px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-self: flex-start;
  }
}

label {
  position: relative;
}

.fa {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -5%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s, color .5s;
}

[data-valid] .fa {
  opacity: 1;
  color: green;
}

[data-valid="valid"] .fa {
  color: green;
}

[data-valid="error"] .fa {
  color: red;
}

.error {
  display: none;
  color: red;
  font-size: .7em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(150%);
}

[data-valid="error"] .error {
  display: block;
} 

function phoneNumber(phone)  {
  var phoneno = /^\d{9}|\d{10}|\d{11}$/;

  console.log("PHONE: "+phoneno.test(phone));
  return phoneno.test(phone);
}

$('input[type="tel"]').on('keyup', function() {
  var $label = $(this).closest('label');
  if ($(this).val().trim() != '') {
    if ($(this).is('#phone')) {
      if (phoneNumber($(this).val())) {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
         $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-times-circle-o").addClass("fa-check-circle");
      } else {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'error');
        console.log("this works");
         $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-check-circle").addClass("fa-times-circle-o");
      }
    } else {
      $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
      console.log("this works")
    }
  } else {
    $label.removeAttr('data-valid');
    console.log("this works")

  }
});


function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

  console.log("email: "+re.test(email));
  return re.test(email);
}

$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function() {
  var $label = $(this).closest('label');
  if ($(this).val().trim() != '') {
    if ($(this).is('#email')) {
      if (validateEmail($(this).val())) {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
        $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-times-circle-o").addClass("fa-check-circle");

      } else {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'error');
        console.log("this works 1")
         $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-check-circle").addClass("fa-times-circle-o");
      }
    } else {
      $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
      console.log("this works 2");
    }
  } else {
    $label.removeAttr('data-valid');
    console.log("this works 3");
  }
});


test = function() {
  if ($("#first_name").val()
      && $("#last_name").val()
      && $("#email").val()
      && $("#phone").val()
      && $("#city").val()
      && $("#state").val()
      && $("#company").val()) {

    $("#sub").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your
 question. Great questions tend to generate quicker, better answers from the community.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using bootstrap? It's a fantastic framework that makes tasks like this super easy.

Comment: I would love to, but the person I am making it for does not want to use any bootstrap.